# Do I need to change my Apps Script code because Google+ Sign-in feature is being deprecated?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-plus-signin

I got this notification saying that "On March 7, 2019, all Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in will be shut down completely. This will be a progressive shutdown, with API calls starting to intermittently fail as early as January 28, 2019, and OAuth requests for Google+ scopes starting to intermittently fail as early as February 15, 2019."

I am asked to "Please update your projects listed below by March 7, 2019 and ensure they are no longer using Google+ APIs, or requesting Google+ OAuth scopes. The data below shows which Google+ API methods your projects have recently called, as well as Google+ OAuth scopes it has requested."

Currently, the authorization is being handled automatically by Google when a user uses a functionality defined by the script that requires access to edit Google Sheets for example.

Here is the doc that shows some migration tips: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide

My question is do I actually need to do anything to my Apps Script code if I am working only in the Google suite like Google Sheets and Forms to ensure this authorization still works after Google moves from Google+ Sign-In to Google Sign-In. I am not doing API calls from a separate website or anything like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Do you populate a sign-in button by yourself using Google Apps Script? If so please share some code, there's probably some work to do. I think this should be the case.

When you publish a Google Apps Script you can choose to run it as the owner of the script or the user accessing the the web-app. Depending on the scopes used in Google Apps Script it will require some authorisation, this is fully handled by Google and there's nothing you should do.